# Magento export customer order in excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

i am working with excel sheet. i want to add two numbers and want to display result both in number and text. if you add one and two the result will be three. i want to display result in both shape like in text and number together. please help me to solve my problem. thanks in advance

Comment: maybe export to CVS instead, as it is much more simple (excel can also read this format).

Comment: thanks for your reply cvs is fine but i need to know the method how can i do this????

Comment: Well if you just want to create a csv file, then PHP's [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function should be enough

Comment: any idea how to create this file caz i m totally new for magento

Comment: please don't forget to up-vote useful answers (and comments), and if you are satisfied with any, mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this extension on magento connect:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-export-orders-to-csv.html

You can install this by your magento admin (just check that this extension is compatible with your magento but it seems to be ok).

Comment: Thanks very much this extension is very good and works for me thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience i think you should go with this extension. I have many used this extension it is working fine for me.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

Comment: this answer might be correct but this extension is for lower version pf PHP i am using higer version of PHP. anyway found the  below extension and works for me. thanks

Comment: Yes for your information this version is working perfect in all php versions.